# InvalidCipherTextException "Pad block corrupt" when decrypting string

Tags: java, encryption, dart, cryptography

I am working on a mobile application using flutter/dart that will communicate with a Java RESTful service. I want to encrypt the user's password, even though we are on a private network, when they attempt to log in.

On the flutter side, I am using the pointy castle dart package. On the Java side, the bouncy castle package. As the user goes to log in, I make a call to the web service to get a 32 randomly generated string and a 16 byte randomly generated string. These will be used as the encryption key and initialization vector respectively. The string are Base64 encoded before sending them back to the mobile application.

When I go to decrypt the string in the RESTful service I receive the error

`javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted`

For encryption and decryption on both sides I'm using AES/CBC/PKCS7 padding.

```
@GET
@Path("key")
public Response generateKey() throws Exception {

    String passphrase = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(32);
    String encodedretVal = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(passphrase.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    System.out.println("Raw passphrase: " + passphrase);
    System.out.println("Encoded passphrase: " + encodedretVal);

    String iv = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(16);
    String encodediv = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    String response = new JSONObject()
            .put("passphrase", encodedretVal)
            .put("iv", encodediv).toString();


    return Response.ok(response, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

The values are decoded and used to encrypt the password. I am using the following code from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/proteye/e54eef1713e1fe9123d1eb04c0a5cf9b)

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:encryption_test/utilities/helpers/gylogger.dart';
import "package:pointycastle/export.dart";

// AES key size
const KEY_SIZE = 32; // 32 byte key for AES-256
const ITERATION_COUNT = 1000;

class AesHelper {
  static const CBC_MODE = 'CBC';
  static const CFB_MODE = 'CFB';

  GyLogger _logger = GyLogger();

  static Uint8List deriveKey(dynamic password, {String salt = '', int iterationCount = ITERATION_COUNT, int derivedKeyLength = KEY_SIZE}) {
    if (password == null || password.isEmpty) {
      throw new ArgumentError('password must not be empty');
    }

    if (password is String) {
      password = createUint8ListFromString(password);
    }

    Uint8List saltBytes = createUint8ListFromString(salt);
    Pbkdf2Parameters params = new Pbkdf2Parameters(saltBytes, iterationCount, derivedKeyLength);
    KeyDerivator keyDerivator = new PBKDF2KeyDerivator(new HMac(new SHA256Digest(), 64));
    keyDerivator.init(params);

    return keyDerivator.process(password);
  }

  static Uint8List pad(Uint8List src, int blockSize) {
    var pad = new PKCS7Padding();
    pad.init(null);

    int padLength = blockSize - (src.length % blockSize);
    var out = new Uint8List(src.length + padLength)..setAll(0, src);
    pad.addPadding(out, src.length);

    return out;
  }

  static Uint8List unpad(Uint8List src) {
    var pad = new PKCS7Padding();
    pad.init(null);

    int padLength = pad.padCount(src);
    int len = src.length - padLength;

    return new Uint8List(len)..setRange(0, len, src);
  }

  static String encrypt(String password, String plaintext, String ivtext, {String mode = CBC_MODE}) {
    Uint8List derivedKey = deriveKey(password);
    KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(derivedKey);
    BlockCipher aes = new AESFastEngine();

    Uint8List iv = createUint8ListFromString(ivtext);

    BlockCipher cipher;
    ParametersWithIV params = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, iv);
    switch (mode) {
      case CBC_MODE:
        cipher = new CBCBlockCipher(aes);
        break;
      case CFB_MODE:
        cipher = new CFBBlockCipher(aes, aes.blockSize);
        break;
      default:
        throw new ArgumentError('incorrect value of the "mode" parameter');
        break;
    }
    cipher.init(true, params);

    Uint8List textBytes = createUint8ListFromString(plaintext);
    Uint8List paddedText = pad(textBytes, aes.blockSize);
    Uint8List cipherBytes = _processBlocks(cipher, paddedText);
    Uint8List cipherIvBytes = new Uint8List(cipherBytes.length + iv.length)..setAll(0, iv)..setAll(iv.length, cipherBytes);
    Uint8List.view(cipherIvBytes.buffer);

    return base64.encode(cipherIvBytes);
  }

  static String decrypt(String password, String ciphertext, String ivtext, {String mode = CBC_MODE}) {
    Uint8List derivedKey = deriveKey(password);
    KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(derivedKey);
    BlockCipher aes = new AESFastEngine();

    Uint8List cipherIvBytes = base64.decode(ciphertext);
    Uint8List iv = new Uint8List(aes.blockSize)..setRange(0, aes.blockSize, cipherIvBytes);

    BlockCipher cipher;
    ParametersWithIV params = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, iv);
    switch (mode) {
      case CBC_MODE:
        cipher = new CBCBlockCipher(aes);
        break;
      case CFB_MODE:
        cipher = new CFBBlockCipher(aes, aes.blockSize);
        break;
      default:
        throw new ArgumentError('incorrect value of the "mode" parameter');
        break;
    }
    cipher.init(false, params);

    int cipherLen = cipherIvBytes.length - aes.blockSize;
    Uint8List cipherBytes = new Uint8List(cipherLen)..setRange(0, cipherLen, cipherIvBytes, aes.blockSize);
    Uint8List paddedText = _processBlocks(cipher, cipherBytes);
    Uint8List textBytes = unpad(paddedText);

    return new String.fromCharCodes(textBytes);
  }

  static Uint8List _processBlocks(BlockCipher cipher, Uint8List inp) {
    var out = new Uint8List(inp.lengthInBytes);

    for (var offset = 0; offset < inp.lengthInBytes;) {
      var len = cipher.processBlock(inp, offset, out, offset);
      offset += len;
    }

    return out;
  }

  static Uint8List createUint8ListFromString(String s) {
    var ret = new Uint8List(s.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      ret[i] = s.codeUnitAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

The encrypted string, encoded key and encoded IV are sent back to the server where I attempt to decrypt the password. I got the following code from this Stack Exchange Code Review [request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/166997)

```
@GET
@Path("secret")
public String decryptPassword(@QueryParam("phrase") String phrase, @QueryParam("key") String passphrase, @QueryParam("iv") String iv) throws Exception {

    passphrase = new String(decoder.decode(passphrase));
    iv = new String(decoder.decode(iv));

    AESEngine engine = new AESEngine();
    CBCBlockCipher blockCipher = new CBCBlockCipher(engine);
    BlockCipherPadding padding = new PKCS7Padding();
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, padding); 
    KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(passphrase.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, iv.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, iv.getBytes("UTF-8").length);

    cipher.init(false, keyParamWithIV);
    byte[] out2 = decoder.decode(phrase);

    byte[] comparisonBytes = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(out2.length)];
    int length = cipher.processBytes(out2, 0, out2.length, comparisonBytes, 0);
    cipher.doFinal(comparisonBytes, length); //Do the final block
    String decrypted = new String(comparisonBytes);
    System.out.println("Decrypted String:" + decrypted);

    return decrypted;
}
```

Each time I try to decrypt the string I receive the following error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:408)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.gy.web.RequestLogger.doFilter(RequestLogger.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.gy.filters.AccessControlFilter.doFilter(AccessControlFilter.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.gy.filters.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:436)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding.padCount(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at com.mfgweb.encryption.EncryptionController.decryptPassword(EncryptionController.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
    ... 44 more
```

In some additional research I found a suggestion to dump the byte array of the encrypted string from both sides, the mobile app and the service, and compare the two. Doing so revealed the following

From Dart Encryption

```
[69,76,56,106,109,67,97,55,122,115,49,120,118,50,104,70,12,3,106,96,19,116,166,72,232,73,221,117,115,143,35,115]
```

From Java Decryption

```
[69,76,56,106,109,67,97,55,122,115,49,120,118,50,104,70,12,3,106,96,19,116,-90,72,-24,73,-35,117,115,-113,35,115]
```

Both are the same length but the Java byte array is showing negative numbers. I believe this is because, from what I understand, the Dart array is an array of unsigned integers where Java is signed. I don't know if this is the issue or not.

I need some help trying to figure this out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would really help everyone, yourself included, if you edit your question and replace the code with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with the emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: You're really not supposed to encrypt then decrypt passwords... The common practice is to hash the password on the client, then send it hashed to the server, which should absolutely not be able to "decrypt" it (hashinig is a one-way process - you can't unhash something - and that's the point!).

Comment: Yes Java language treats `byte` as signed, but Java _crypto_ (and also I/O) treats them as unsigned by masking when needed, which is fine (if occasionally cluttered). Your error is because in Dart you used a key _derived_ from the passphrase using PBKDF2 (with empty salt?!) while in Java you used the passphrase directly as the key, which is a completely different thing. However I concur with Renato you shouldn't encrypt _passwords_ in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment: passwords are not supposed to be encrypted/decrypted. This is not how passwords are handled for decades now.

You need to hash the password with a salt, which is a one-way process which cannot be reverted, protecting the original password from ever being discovered once it's been hashed... that's why you want to hash it as soon as possible.

Luckily, all this code you posted can be thrown away as there's a Flutter package which will use the strongest currently utilized hashing algorithm available, Argon2: https://pub.dev/packages/encryptions

Other algorithms in common use are bcrypt and scrypt.

Here's how you do it in Dart:

```
Uint8List password = utf8.encode("password");
Uint8List salt = utf8.encode("helloworld");

Argon2 argon2 = Argon2(iterations: 16, hashLength: 64, memory: 256, parallelism: 2);
Uint8List hash = await argon2.argon2i(password, salt);

// send hash to the server
```

Now, no the Java side, all you have to do is compare the String with what you've got in the database... you don't need to know the original password, and you shouldn't ever know that. Users tend to re-use passwords, so the last thing you want is for the plain text password to be available in your database for others to steal.

You probably don't even want to load the hash from the database: just ask the database to get the user only if the password matches:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :userId AND password_hash = :passwordHash
```

This way, the actual hash of the user's password doesn't even leave the DB.

If for whatever reason, you need to hash passwords also in Java (e.g. you want to keep the salt on the server side only or you have other clients than Flutter that cannot perform hashing), it's about as easy as in Dart using this library: https://github.com/phxql/argon2-jvm

```
// Create instance
Argon2Advanced argon2 = Argon2Factory.createAdvanced();

// Read password from user
char[] password = readPasswordFromUser();

// Hash password
String hash = argon2.hash(iterations, memory, parallelism,
                          password, charset, salt)
```

Comment: salt should be unique for each password hashed, not constant, which means it needs to be stored with the hash result, and fetched and used on verification; it is commonly convenient to use a RNG to generate a unique value, although there can be other methods.

Comment: If you do the login in two stages, it's possible to load the salt before you actually verify the password... but I agree in general, the salt should be unique.

Comment: @Renato, Thanks for the comments and answer. However, I cannot hash the password because I need to use that password to actually log in the user on an IBM AS/400. This is why I am encrytping/decrypting. I do not wish to transfer the password in plain text.

Comment: To encrypt it on the client, you would need a key on the client, making the whole exercise pointless, no? Or you're trying to encrypt using a public key on the client, which only the server can decrypt using the private key (which the client can't see)? That's the only safe way you could achieve that I think, and that's not what you're doing in your posted example.

Comment: See how to use a private key to decrypt content in Java here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-asymmetric-cryptography-example/ and a public key to encrypt in dart here: https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt#asymmetric (notice Dart won't need the private key!)

Comment: @Renato, I went with generating unique one time use public/private keys. Sending the public key to the client, encrypting the password, then sending the credentials back to the server to log them in. Thanks for the ideas